# How to store a list of IP addresses in SQL variable?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

The goal is to query multiple IP addresses. I am using HeidiSQL to run this query.

Error:

> SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax;check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near "10.3.22.14" at line 1.

SQL query:

```
set @trunk='10.3.22.5','10.3.22.14';
set @sdate='2021-06-29 00:00:00', @edate='2021-06-29 23:59:00';
SELECT acctstarttime, acctstoptime, acctsessiontime, calledstationid, callingstationid, username, acctterminatecause, h323disconnectcause, h323calltype, acctstatustype, nasipaddress, nasportid, h323remoteaddress, acctinputoctets, servicetype, acctoutputoctets
FROM radius.radacct
where (acctstarttime between @sdate and @edate )
and nasipaddress in (@trunk);
```

[image: 1]

How can I fix this syntax error?

Answer (score 1):

You can not define a list as variable.

```sql
set @trunk='10.3.22.5','10.3.22.14';
```

Define a comma-separated list, and use `FIND_IN_SET`.

```sql
set @trunk='10.3.22.5,10.3.22.14';
select FIND_IN_SET('10.3.22.5', @trunk);
```

[refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53397668/mysql-set-a-variable-with-a-list)

Comment: Do not use dquotes `"` as string literal delimiters in MySQL. They're used as JSON values delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

First, I don't really recommend what you are doing.  But to get the correct syntax, you need to realize that `'` is a special character in SQL.  It is a string delimiter.  So:

```
set @trunk='10.3.22.5','10.3.22.14';
```

is just two strings next to each other.  And MariaDB does not recognize that syntax.  What you are trying to do is:

```
set @trunc = '10.3.22.5,10.3.22.14'
```

Then, you can use this in the query not with `in`, but using `find_in_set()`:

```
where find_in_set(nasipaddress, @trunc) > 0
```

Note that using the function `find_in_set()` prevents the use of indexes.  So, if your table is large, then another solution is preferable, perhaps by storing the values in a table and using `join`.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot define list as a variable.

set @trunk="10.3.22.5,10.3.22.14";
select FIND_IN_SET("10.3.22.5", @trunk);

Comment: It would help if you would include the complete statement with your enhancement, for better context. Also, try using code formatting when including code in your answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks